# Windows Zookeeper Cluster

Tags: windows, apache-zookeeper

I would like to understand if it is possible to run a Zookeeper cluster on Windows and if so, how to set it up. If it is not possible, given that it is a Java application, I would like to understand why.

From my research, it seems Windows is supported for standalone setup and to aid in development but not for production [zookeeper system requirements](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_systemReq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Zookeeper 3.4.9, Windows is supported for production.  From [ZooKeeper Administrator's Guide 3.4.9](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_supportedPlatforms):

[image]

Comment: Looks like this came about from ZOOKEEPER-2243 - Supported platforms is completely out of date - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2243